# How can input from keyboard in array in java

Tags: java, input, java.util.scanner

In my program there is some error so pls help me

```
package string_demo;

import java.util.Scanner;

public class array_find_min_max_no {

    static void min(int arr[]){  

        //arr=Integer.parseInt();
        int min=arr[0];  
        int max=arr[0];
        for(int i=1;i<arr.length;i++) { 

            if(min>arr[i])  {
                min=arr[i];  
            }
            if(max<arr[i]) {
                max=arr[i];  
            }
        }
        System.out.println(min);
        System.out.println(max); 
    }  

    public static void main(String args[]){
        Scanner sc=new Scanner(System.in);
        int b[]=sc.next();
        min(b);//passing array in the method  
    } 
}
```

Comment: If the input is 12 24 35 31
sc.next() return string, so you can use sc.next.split(" ");
Then iterate through String array and use Integer.parseInt(String)

Answer (score 2):

Here you need to convert the input string(as `sc.next()`) to string array then string array to int array.

> [Scanner#next()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html#next%28%29) - Finds and returns the next complete token from this
>   scanner. A complete token is preceded and followed by input that
>   matches the delimiter pattern.

There are no shortcut or method provided to convert string array to int array, so you need to parse the string array and convert (using [`Integer#parseInt`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Integer.html#parseInt%28java.lang.String%29)) the each element individually and put into the integer into new integer array

```
...
String b[]=sc.next().split(","); // assume input is comma seperated string
int[] data = new int[items.length];

for (int i = 0; i < b.length; i++) {
    try {
        data[i] = Integer.parseInt(b[i]);
    } catch (NumberFormatException nfe) {};
}
min(data);
...
```

Answer (score 0):

it's:

```
int m;
Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
System.out.println("enter the number of elements you will enter");
m = sc.nextInt();
int b[] = new int[m];
for(int i = 0; i < m; i++){
    b[i] = sc.nextInt();
}
```

Comment: `Scanner.nextInt()` returns an `int`, not an `int[]` (int array).

Comment: This won't work either because `int` is a primitive type, not a reference. Assigning `d` a value won't change the value in the array which will still be full of 0s. Not to mention that your solution requires knowing `x`.

Comment: yes you're right: when it's a primitif java make a copy, but if objects java give the same reference to the second variable. I change I hope that this will work for him